# Asp.Net Core 3.1 - Display SubCategory After choose parent with Ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I want the related subcategory to be displayed when the main category is selected ?But nothing is displayed

Query :

```
 List<Category> IAdmin.ShowSubCategory(Guid catid)
    {
        return _context.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == catid).ToList();
    }
```

View :

```
$("#maincategory").change(function () {
    $("#ParentId").empty();
    $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/GetSubCategory/" + $("#maincategory :selected").val(),
        function (data) {
            $.each(data,
                function () {
                    $("#ParentId").append('<option value= ' + this.value + '>' + this.text + '</option>');
                })
        }
    )
});
```

Controller :

```
  public IActionResult GetSubCategory(Guid id)
    {           
        
        var SubCategory_List = _admin.ShowSubCategory(id);
        return Json(SubCategory_List);          
       
    }
```

Undefined is displayed in dropdown list after select parent

Comment: Does GetSubCategory Action get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Useed this :

```
 return Json(new SelectList(SubCategory_List, "CategoryId", "CategoryTitle"));
```

thats worked